# What is the Gogs ROOT_URL Configuration parameter for?

Tags: gogs

Gogs has the following server configuration parameters:

```
[server]
DOMAIN       = 172.17.0.2
HTTP_PORT    = 3000
ROOT_URL     = http://172.17.0.2:3000/
```

So the `ROOT_URL` parameter could be constructed from the `DOMAIN` and the `HTTP_PORT` the way it is shown above.  Is it used in scenarios where Gogs cannot derive it?

TIA,
Ole

Comment: can you please share how would you make git.example.com listen to port 3000 while example,com listens to port 80 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So the `ROOT_URL` parameter could be constructed from the `DOMAIN` and the `HTTP_PORT`

That is not always true. The `HTTP_PORT` is the port gogs listens for incoming traffic, but this does not necessarily mean that you can reach gogs under that port.

For example, I let gogs listen on port 3000 on localhost, however gogs is available under `git.example.com` because my apache server, listening on port 80, acts as a proxy and redirects traffic for this subdomain to gogs. If you couldn't configure the `ROOT_URL` yourself and gogs would just take the `DOMAIN` and `PORT` to create the full URL, this wouldn't be possible because gogs would gegerate wrong links and wrong clone-urls.

Comment: can you please share how would you make `git.example.com` listen to port 3000 while example,com listens to port 80 ?